# htaccess rewrite for variable

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Okay, so this is my current HTACCESS file however it doesn't seem to be rewriting the variable properly, I'm not strong with htaccess so no clue I've found these from different sources,

The first rewrite allows me to use /item123/ however still shows ?searchid=item123 when searched by the server, I'd like to be written in the url as /item123/ Cheers. I think it needs a 301 redirect from server as mines not working.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([0-9A-z]+)/?$ /profile.php?searchid=$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*404\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)404\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to rewrite first group (the content before the first slash) because then it will most likely get caught no matter the url. As so, you should use something like
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9A-z]+)/?$

You dont need permanent redirect.

How the url appears depends totally on how you set it up. I'm guessing you're using a form to submit value of user to search for it. The form uses that GET format you said. You can, however, use a middle page that redirects it to the /item123/ format you want immediately.

Comment: As I said, I'm not confident with htaccess haha, how would I do the middle page, as i do need to hide the ?searchid=item123  -> indefinitely?

Comment: I suggest you add method="post" in the <form> then, in profile.php you use this code in the beginning
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["searchid"])){ header("Location: /search/".$_POST["searchid"]);
?>

This will check if a POST request with that form field was submitted and redirect it to itself (according to the .htaccess that follows). Switch that first rule for
RewriteRule ^search/([0-9A-z]+)/?$ /profile.php?searchid=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Using post, wouldn't that disable users being able to go to examle.com/item123/ ? Thats why I used GET, as you can just URL it, I was hoping for a simple 301 redirect or something, so if the url is returned as `?searchid=$1 then redirect as /$1/` so it would look like `example.com/item123/ not example.com?searchid=item123`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the R=301 (REDIRECT) flag to internally redirect the request

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([0-9A-z]+)/?$ /profile.php?searchid=$1 [NC,L]
```